# how can I have Infinite pager in mini_page views?

Tags: 7, views

I need my minipager to go infinite. I mean when it get to the last record to jump to the the first one. If it goes to the last one jump to the first one? How can I achieve this. I am using views to display my information. But I just want it to use it in a particular view. I don't want it to be default for all my views.

[image: Infinite pager]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this [reference views mini pager](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!theme!theme.inc/function/theme_views_mini_pager/7). In order to do this in your template.php you need to call the function for that view mini pager. In order to find out which is the best for you, use the theme developer module.

The trick is to change what happens when empty($li_previous)) and (empty($li_next)). If there is a better way to accomplish this, please let me know.

```
function my_theme_name_views_mini_pager__yourview($variables){
```

> global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

```
$tags = $vars['tags'];
  $element = $vars['element'];
  $parameters = $vars['parameters'];
  $quantity = $vars['quantity'];



  // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
  // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
  $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
  // current is the page we are currently paged to
  $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
  // max is the maximum page number
  // first is the first page listed by this pager piece (re quantity)
  $pager_first = $pager_current - $pager_middle + 1;



  $pager_last = $pager_current + $quantity - $pager_middle;
  // max is the maximum page number

  $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
  // End of marker calculations.


  if ($pager_total[$element] > 1) {
  $li_previous = theme('pager_previous', 
  array(
  'text' => (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : t('')), 
  'element' => $element, 
  'interval' => 1, 
  'parameters' => $parameters,
)
);    


if (empty($li_previous)) {
  $li_last = theme('pager_last',
   array('text' => (isset($tags[4]) ? $tags[4] : t('')), 
  'element' => $element, 
  'parameters' => $parameters));    

  $li_previous =$li_last;



}



$li_next = theme('pager_next', 
  array(
  'text' => (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('')), 
  'element' => $element, 
  'interval' => 1, 
  'parameters' => $parameters,
)
);

if (empty($li_next)) {
  $li_first = theme('pager_first', array('text' => (isset($tags[0]) ? $tags[0] : t('')), 'element' => $element, 'parameters' => $parameters));  
  $li_next = $li_first;

}

$items[] = array(
  'class' => array('pager-previous'), 
  'data' => $li_previous,
);

$items[] = array(
  'class' => array('pager-current'), 
  'data' => t('@current of @max', array('@current' => $pager_current, '@max' => $pager_max)),
);

$items[] = array(
  'class' => array('pager-next'), 
  'data' => $li_next,
);


return theme('item_list', 
  array(
  'items' => $items, 
  'title' => NULL, 
  'type' => 'ul', 
  'attributes' => array('class' => array('pager')),
)
);
```

}

```
}
```